# Do not evaluate function composition in total derivative

Tags: functions, variational-calculus

How to achieve that `Dt[]` does not touch certain function compositions, but still applies all the other derivative transformations. Example:

```
(* want *)
Dt[t f[x], t] = f[x] + t Dt[f[x], t]

(* get *)
Dt[t f[x], t] = f[x] + t Dt[x, t] f'[x]
```

---

*Context: I am doing quantum field theory calculations and want to use Dt for derivatives of fields. For that I need the `Conjugate[]` of fields, which should be kept unevaluated by `Dt[]`.*

*Bonus points: Make `Conjugate[]` commute with `Dt[]`, i.e.*

```
Conjugate[Dt[Conjugate[x], t]] = Dt[x, t]
```

Comment: I assume the "want" line should be `f[x] + t Dt[f[x], t]`?

Comment: I think the only easy way to get your desired output is by just leaving out the `x` dependence: `Dt[t f, t]`

Comment: Mathematica can be given assumptions (via `Assumptions` or `Assuming`). Maybe telling Mathematica that x does not depend on t does the trick

Comment: also, assuming that x is independent of t, shouldn't Dt[f[x],t] evaluate to zero?

Comment: I think defining f more clearly would be helpful, i.e. what is its domain and codomain?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit yes, thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change a system option so that derivatives of [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate) are not performed:

```
old = OptionValue[
    SystemOptions[],
    "DifferentiationOptions"->"ExcludedFunctions"
]

SetSystemOptions[
    "DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> DeleteDuplicates[Append[old, Conjugate]]
]
```

> {Hold, HoldComplete, Less, LessEqual, Greater, GreaterEqual, Inequality, 
> Unequal, Nand, Nor, Xor, Not, Element, Exists, ForAll, Implies, Positive, 
> Negative, NonPositive, NonNegative, Replace, ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated}

> "DifferentiationOptions" -> {"AlwaysThreadGradients" -> False,
> "DifferentiateHeads" -> True, "DifferentiateIteratorIndexed" -> True,
> "DirectHighDerivatives" -> True, "DirectHighDerivativeThreshold" -> 10,
> "ExcludedFunctions" -> {Hold, HoldComplete, Less, LessEqual, Greater,
> GreaterEqual, Inequality, Unequal, Nand, Nor, Xor, Not, Element, Exists,
> ForAll, Implies, Positive, Negative, NonPositive, NonNegative, Replace,
> ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated, Conjugate}, "ExitOnFailure" -> False,
> "HighDerivativeMaxTerms" -> 1000,
> "SymbolicAutomaticDifferentiation" -> False}

Then, you can use [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) to define how [`Dt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dt) should behave with [`Conjugate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conjugate):

```
Unprotect[Conjugate];
Conjugate /: Dt[Conjugate[f_], d__] := Conjugate[Dt[f, d]]
Protect[Conjugate];
```

Then:

```
Dt[t Conjugate[x], t]
```

> Conjugate[x] + t Conjugate[Dt[x, t]]

and:

```
Conjugate[Dt[Conjugate[x], t]]
```

> Dt[x, t]

Resetting to defaults:

```
SetSystemOptions["DifferentiationOptions" -> "ExcludedFunctions" -> old]
```

> "DifferentiationOptions" -> {"AlwaysThreadGradients" -> False,
> "DifferentiateHeads" -> True, "DifferentiateIteratorIndexed" -> True,
> "DirectHighDerivatives" -> True, "DirectHighDerivativeThreshold" -> 10,
> "ExcludedFunctions" -> {Hold, HoldComplete, Less, LessEqual, Greater,
> GreaterEqual, Inequality, Unequal, Nand, Nor, Xor, Not, Element, Exists,
> ForAll, Implies, Positive, Negative, NonPositive, NonNegative, Replace,
> ReplaceAll, ReplaceRepeated}, "ExitOnFailure" -> False,
> "HighDerivativeMaxTerms" -> 1000,
> "SymbolicAutomaticDifferentiation" -> False}

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think `f` was just a stand-in for `Conjugate`.

Comment: Carl Woll is right. Thanks, that's exactly the type of solution I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Getting system functions to behave different from the way they were designed is in general a rather difficult task. One option, I strongly advise against, would be unprotecting the function and adding custom definitions for special cases. For relatively simple tasks I found it easier (and much saver) to write my own function/wrappers. Depending on how much functionality of `Dt` OP really needs this could be a good starting point.

```
ClearAll[dt];

dt[f_[x_,y__],t_]:=f@@(dt[#,t]&/@{x,y})/;MemberQ[{Plus,List},f]
dt[Times[a_,b__],t_]:=dt[a,t]*b+a dt[Times[b],t]
dt[Conjugate[a_],t_]:=Conjugate[dt[a,t]]
dt[a_,t_]:=With[{dta=Dt[a,t]},dta/;ContainsNone[Level[dta,-1,Heads->True],{Derivative,Dt}]]

dt[t f[x],t]
Conjugate[dt[Conjugate[x],t]]
```

returning the desired output

```
t dt[f[x], t] + f[x]
dt[x, t]
```

This code distributes `dt` over `Plus` and `List`, uses the product rule on `Times`, commutes with `Conjugate` (for those sweet bonus points OP is talking about) and then tries to use `Dt`. `Dt` is only applied if the resulting expression is free of derivatives (`Derivative` and `Dt`), which prevents partial derivatives like `f'[x]` but allows for e.g. `dt[t^2 Sin[t], t]` to evaluate (to `t^2 Cos[t]+2 t Sin[t]`) using the differentiation tools of `Dt`.

In terms of performance a manual implementation like this is slower then `Dt` but still very fast. If performance becomes a problem or such a custom implementation is unsuited using rules to eliminate `f[x]` in intermediate steps as suggested by Sjoerd Smit in the comment of OPs question might be the better option.